# Difference of letting DataFrame's column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I don't know the difference of two ways that I let columns of DataFrame.
the codes are here:

```
# let X be any 2-d array.
A=pd.DataFrame(data=X, columns=['ftr1', 'ftr2'])
A['ftr3']=1
print(A['ftr3'])

B=pd.DataFrame(data=X, columns=[['ftr1', 'ftr2']])
B['ftr3']=1
print(B['ftr3'])
```

when I printed A['ftr3'] to see elements of ftr3 of A, there was no problem.

But when I printed B['ftr3'], the problem occured:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Moreover, the reason I'm confused with this result was that print(A) and print(B) prints exactly same results.

```
A=pd.DataFrame(data=X, columns=['ftr1', 'ftr2'])
A['ftr3']=1
print(A)
B=pd.DataFrame(data=X, columns=[['ftr1', 'ftr2']])
B['ftr3']=1
print(B)
```

the results are here:

print(A)
[image: print(A)]

print(B)
[image: print(B)]

I don't get the points..plz help and thank for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `print(B[['ftr3']])` instead of `print(B['ftr3'])`

The architecture of the columns is not the same : use `A.columns` and `B.columns` to compare them.

`A.columns` will return : `Index(['ftr1', 'ftr2', 'ftr3'], dtype='object')`
`B.columns` will return : `MultiIndex([('ftr1',),('ftr2',),('ftr3',)],)`

Comment: I newly get the concept of MultiIndex! THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWER.
however, I still do not understand why I can't access to B['ftr3']. ftr1 and ftr2 is used as a MultiIndex because I entered [ ['ftr1', 'ftr2]] as dataframe B's column. but ftr3 was not like that. I just normally added ftr3 column. Can you explain why this occured?